# Can a Flex 3 app launch and pass data back and forth to a Flex 4 app?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flash-builder

We have a large Flex 3 app that we do not have time to convert over to Flex 4 at this point.  However, we want to use a component set that is currently implemented in Flex 4.
The idea is for us to have our main Flex 3 app launch a Flex 4 app.  We need to be able to pass data from the Flex 3 app to the Flex 4 app and back again.

Is this possible?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something at runtime, then you need to research the [LocalConnection](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) object to communicate between two SWFs.  It won't matter how those swfs were created.  You can use Flex 4, Flex 4, or even Flash Pro.

If you only want to share components between the two projects at compile time, unfortunately you'll need to create two separate projects; as Flex 3 SWCs cannot be used with Flex 4 [and vice versa].

Comment: Thanks Flextras - this was a huge help.  We are just trying to make some calls back and forth and not sharing any components so this seems like it may be exactly what we need.